# How to format decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to format float like price for two decimal places and thousands spaces, like this: 
"1 082 233.00"

Answer (score 10):

Use `number_to_currency` or `number_with_precision`:

```
number_with_precision(1082233, :precision => 2,
                               :separator => '.',
                               :delimiter => ' ')
# => '1 082 233.00'
```

See the [NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) documentation for details.